# API call in Flutter & convert MAP to List

Tags: flutter

Trying to use the HAPIBOOK API in RapidAPI [1](https://rapidapi.com/roftcomp-laGmBwlWLm/api/hapi-books/) for flutter, but with no success. As I see in the log I need to convert MAP to list which I already did in the custom class but still getting the error, if there will be an explanation for it would be amazing.

***CUSTOM CLASS***

```
import 'dart:convert';

HapiBook hapiBookFromJson(String str) => HapiBook.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hapiBookToJson(HapiBook data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class HapiBook {
  HapiBook({
    required this.bookId,
    required this.name,
    required this.cover,
    required this.url,
    required this.authors,
    required this.rating,
    required this.pages,
    required this.publishedDate,
    required this.synopsis,
  });

  int bookId;
  String name;
  String cover;
  String url;
  List<String> authors;
  int rating;
  int pages;
  String publishedDate;
  String synopsis;

  factory HapiBook.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HapiBook(
        bookId: json["book_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        cover: json["cover"],
        url: json["url"],
        authors: List<String>.from(json["authors"].map((x) => x)),
        rating: json["rating"],
        pages: json["pages"],
        publishedDate: json["published_date"],
        synopsis: json["synopsis"],
      );

  static List<HapiBook> hapiBookfromsnapshot(List snapshot) {
    return snapshot.map((data) {
      return HapiBook.fromJson(data);
    }).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "book_id": bookId,
        "name": name,
        "cover": cover,
        "url": url,
        "authors": List<dynamic>.from(authors.map((x) => x)),
        "rating": rating,
        "pages": pages,
        "published_date": publishedDate,
        "synopsis": synopsis,
      };
}
```

**API CALL**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:fluttrapi2/models/hapi_book_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FetchApi {
  static Future<List<HapiBook>?> fetchBooks() async {
    var url = Uri.https('hapi-books.p.rapidapi.com', '/book/56597885');
    final res = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'mY KEY',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'hapi-books.p.rapidapi.com'
    });
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      Map json = jsonDecode(res.body);

      return HapiBook.hapiBookfromsnapshot(json);
    }
  }
}
```

Error

```
E/flutter ( 5614): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
E/flutter ( 5614): #0      FetchApi.fetchBooks
package:fluttrapi2/controler/hapi_book_api.dart:14
E/flutter ( 5614): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5614): #1      _HomePageState.getdatas
package:fluttrapi2/views/hom_page.dart:24
E/flutter ( 5614): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5614):
```

**Json :**

```
{"book_id":56597885
"name":"Beautiful World, Where Are You"
"cover":"https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1618329605l/56597885.jpg"
"url":"https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/56597885"
"authors":[1 item
0:"Sally Rooney"
]
"rating":3
"pages":356
"published_date":"September 7th 2021"
"synopsis":"Beautiful World, Where Are You is a new novel by Sally Rooney, the bestselling author of Normal People and Conversations with Friends.Alice, a novelist, meets Felix, who works in a warehouse, and asks him if he’d like to travel to Rome with her. In Dublin, her best friend, Eileen, is getting over a break-up and slips back into flirting with Simon, a man she has known sinceBeautiful World, Where Are You is a new novel by Sally Rooney, the bestselling author of Normal People and Conversations with Friends.Alice, a novelist, meets Felix, who works in a warehouse, and asks him if he’d like to travel to Rome with her. In Dublin, her best friend, Eileen, is getting over a break-up and slips back into flirting with Simon, a man she has known since childhood. Alice, Felix, Eileen, and Simon are still young—but life is catching up with them. They desire each other, they delude each other, they get together, they break apart. They have sex, they worry about sex, they worry about their friendships and the world they live in. Are they standing in the last lighted room before the darkness, bearing witness to something? Will they find a way to believe in a beautiful world?"
}
```

rying to use the HAPIBOOK API in RapidAPI for flutter, but with no success. As I see in the log I need to convert MAP to list which I already did in the custom class but still getting the error, if there will be an explanation for it would be amazing.

Comment: Mind to share *what* error you get?

Comment: But as I see it, you are calling `HapiBook.hapiBookfromsnapshot` with a parameter `json` of type `Map` but it expects a parameter of type `List`.

Comment: I tried this one map.forEach((k, v) => list.add(json(k, v)));  ???

Comment: Where did you try that, and what did you do with the result?

Comment: IN the API CALL CLASS. but this method already depreciated.

Comment: Can you share the JSON response you are trying to convert?

Comment: https://rapidapi.com/roftcomp-laGmBwlWLm/api/hapi-books/

Comment: Can include JSON in question

Comment: No one???know this